# How to install missing dependency when package is being installed into the app

Tags: angular, npm

I'm developing and npm library inside the company, let's call it `@org/my-lib`.

I need to add an npm package that this library depends on as peerDependency (this library is called `@angular/material`). However I would like to automate this process i.e. when somebody installs my library

`npm i @org/my-lib`

then I would like to automatically install `@angular/material` in consuming project and install `@angular/material` version that will match the version of angular that the project (consuming app) is using.

The reason is the following: I don't want the developers of consuming apps to complain about breaking change and that they need to install `@angular/material` on their own.

Is there a way to achieve it?

Comment: will this work for you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53289082/how-to-bundle-include-dependencies-in-angular-cli-libraries

Comment: Rather not, is the app already has @angular/material then it should use whatever is installed at app level

Comment: Unless I'm misunderstanding then from an enterprise perspective that's a great example of why npm/yarn etc now support a package-lock feature and an oudated /  audit feature, so even if I consumed your package and saw your version isn't what I wanted (and if I knew the newer was compatible) than I could still specify like `"dependencies": { "@your/lib": { "requires": { "@angular/material": "^1.2.3.4" }}}` and control that from the consuming application's package-lock.json file and circumvent a need in many cases for an update to the package dependent on it.